# Cannot Access All the View fields Through Reflection

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection, view

I am trying to access the Android View property `mAttributes` [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java;l=5235?q=View.java&ss=android). Since it is public property, I tried to access it like this.

```kotlin
View(this).mAttributes
```

But it didn't work. It says cannot resolve symbol `mAttributes`.

I tried to use reflection API to remove the annotation `@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty` from that property to see if it works that way.

However `View(this).javaClass.declaredFields` doesn't show that property at all.

Not just that, `View(this).javaClass.declaredFields` doesn't show some properties like
`private CharSequence mContentDescription;` as well.

For example, if we take a look at Android View source code, [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java;l=4489?q=View.java&ss=android) you can see a private property `mContentDescription`.

If you try accessing that field using reflection like below, it throws error saying  `No field mContentDescription in class Landroid/view/View; (declaration of 'android.view.View' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)`

```kotlin
View(this).javaClass.getDeclaredField("mContentDescription")
```

I'm confused why reflection API returns only some of the declared fields.

Comment: please put your code here.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces